# Div not Adjusting Height Based on Contents

Tags: html, css, css-float, height

I can't seem to figure out why my info-container div won't adjust its height based upon its contents. I do have a floating div within it and I think it might be causing the problem, but I'm not completely sure. I have a link to jsfiddle where you can see the CSS and some HTML if it helps. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the CSS for the info-container ID holding the float and all other information

```
    #info-container{
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:#6F90A2;
    min-width:1000px;
    max-width:1000px;
    clear: both;
    height:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r35K4/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto;` to `#info-container`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r35K4/3/)**

Floating the child element removes it from the document flow and the parent will collapse. By adding the overflow rule, the desired behavior is restored.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the insight on floats, you were spot on!

Answer (score 7):

```
#info-container{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need what is known as the CSS clearfix. This can be achieved with the following CSS.

```
#info-container:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/r35K4/4/)**

This will create a pseudo element that will force the wrapper to wrap the floated children.

This is arguably a cleaner solution that adding an `overflow` property, as the overflow property has other uses and depending on the case can cause problems with hidden overflow or internal scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xijine/1/edit)**

Create a CSS class:

```
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
  content:" ";
  display:table;
}
.clear:after {
  clear:both;
}
```

and simply apply it to your

```
<div id="info-container" class="clear">
```

or to any other element that contains *Floated* elements which you're having problems with.

---

If you want to do it simpler, use

```
overflow : auto;
```

for any parent element containing floated children, **if you're able to do so** due to the fact that will become an *overflow* element